# How do I add a circle in which the radius is the range in miles/km using ggmap?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geospatial, ggmap

I have created script with the town I want to map. I added:

```
town <- get_stamenmap(
  bbox = c(left = 3.07628, bottom = 45.77407, right = 3.08797, top = 45.77905),
  maptype = "terrain",
  zoom = 16) 
ggmap(town)
```

Then, to let R know where the center of my would-be circle is, I added:

```
lat <- c(45.7765976040585)
long <- c(3.0818176532603374)
town_cor <- data.frame(lat,long)
```

I am now trying to figure out how to use the coordinates set under "town_cor" to create a circle around that point that is 500 meters. I have not found anything that works so far. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119736/ggmap-create-circle-symbol-where-radius-represents-distance-miles-or-km